# почему получается -1 при сужающем приведении примитивных типов, а ещё почему не вылетает ArifmeticException

Tags: java, типы

```
byte c = (byte) (0);
double f = (char) 1234.15;

System.out.println((short)(f/c));
```

Comment: Потому что тип double кроме реальных значений поддерживает еще и функциональные значения типа NaN и +/-Infinity. Деление на ноль и дает результат +Inf.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478429/casting-a-double-to-another-numeric-type нашел что то  похожее на ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArifmeticException` не вылетает потому что делимое - вещественный, а не целочисленный тип (был бы int, long и т.д. - получили бы исключение)
В случае с вещественными типами вы получаете `Infinity` ("+"-бесконечность), что при приведении к `short` дает -1 (из-за переполнения `short`)